# How to draw over other apps with flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have an Android app which renders a FAB with fan out options over other apps (like AZ Screen recorder. Refer image). I want to leverage Flutter for its ease of implementation for animations to render the UI for this overlay. I did not find any resources for this specific case under [Add flutter to existing app](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app) section. Is it possible to use flutter to render this UI?

On android, I use the `WindowManager.addView` to add and later update the UI for overlay.

[image: AZ Screen recorder overlay]